# pick the latest data set when doing geom_hline in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

dput(x)

```
structure(list(Host = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "A", class = "factor"), TimeStamp = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("1/11/2013", 
"1/12/2013", "1/13/2013", "1/14/2013", "1/15/2013"), class = "factor"), 
    Instance = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("/application", "/db"), class = "factor"), 
    Free_Space = c(5048L, 5049L, 6000L, 4800L, 5100L, 317659L, 
    340000L, 350000L, 356666L, 370000L), Used_Space = c(3017L, 
    56000L, 60000L, 55000L, 54000L, 271657L, 150000L, 175000L, 
    165000L, 189999L), Total_Space = c(8064L, 61049L, 66000L, 
    59800L, 59100L, 589316L, 490000L, 525000L, 521666L, 559999L
    )), .Names = c("Host", "TimeStamp", "Instance", "Free_Space", 
"Used_Space", "Total_Space"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I have this data frame. I drive the column name Total_Space by adding Free_Space and Used_Space using data.table package given the Host, TimeStamp and Instance.

```
x<-data.table(x)
x<-x[,Total_Space:=Free_Space+Used_Space, by=c("Host", "Instance", "TimeStamp")]
```

I like to use ggplot facet_wrap from ggplot2 to graph used space in  GB and draw a geom_line by the Total_Space so that users can see how much head room there are.

For example, I am doing this:

```
ggplot(x, aes(TimeStamp, Used_Space/1024, group=Instance)) + geom_area(fill="blue") + geom_smooth(method="lm", colour="orange",se=T, size=1) + geom_hline(data=x, aes(yintercept = Total_Space/1024), col="red")+ facet_wrap(~Host+Instance, ncol=3, scales="free")
```

The problem I am seeing is that I get multiple geom_hline for the same instnace and host, due to Total_Space is changing.

My question is, how can I pick the latest time stamp when doing geom_hline for each instance and Host? I need to show the latest Total_Space in geom_hline.

I tried this approach:

x<-x[,LatestTS:=tail(p[order(p$TimeStamp),],1)$Total_Space, by=c("Host", "Instance", "TimeStamp")]

did not work. it picks the same number for all instances.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution would be, first, make your column `TimeStamp` to dates

```
x$TimeStamp<-as.Date(x$TimeStamp,format="%m/%d/%Y")
```

Then, as your data object is `data.table`, you can subset data according to `Host` and `Instance` and set `TimeStamp` should be maximal value.

```
x[,.SD[TimeStamp==max(TimeStamp)],by="Host,Instance"]
   Host     Instance  TimeStamp Free_Space Used_Space Total_Space
1:    A /application 2013-01-15       5100      54000       59100
2:    A          /db 2013-01-15     370000     189999      559999
```

Now you can use this line inside `geom_hline()`. With `scale_x_date()` you will get now more possibilities to control this scale.

```
library(scales)
ggplot(x, aes(TimeStamp, Used_Space/1024, group=Instance)) + 
  geom_area(fill="blue") + geom_smooth(method="lm", colour="orange",se=T, size=1) + 
  geom_hline(data=x[,.SD[TimeStamp==max(TimeStamp)],by="Host,Instance"], aes(yintercept = Total_Space/1024), col="red")+ 
  facet_wrap(~Host+Instance, ncol=3, scales="free") +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%m/%d/%Y"))
```

[image]